# Add integration tests for API gateway endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, integration-testing, api-gateway

I have implemented an API gateway in .NET Core and I want to write functional tests to verify the behavior of the endpoints in the API gateway. I am using **TestServer** to test integration events between microservices, but I am not sure how to use it to test the endpoints in the API gateway. Is it possible to use `WebApplicationFactory` to write functional tests for the **API gateway endpoints** and make simple HTTP requests to these endpoints to get the result?

I am using `TestServer` to make http calls to different services which I use mostly for checking if `IntegrationEvents` are handled correctly but I can not use it for `API gateway` endpoints:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer identityServer = new IdentityScenariosBase().CreateServer();
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer productServer = new ProductScenariosBase().CreateServer();
        
    HttpClient identityClient = identityServer.CreateClient();    
    HttpClient productClient = productServer .CreateClient();

    // Some other codes
```

And I know that as an alternative I can call all the processes of `API gateway` endpoints in  a test method like above code sample but I want to make one simple http call to an endpoint ***in*** `API gateway` and get the result.